# UniqueEntity Validation on Column+ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: symfony

I tried creating a multi column unique validation constraint but it won't work. Here is my model:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity({"webinar", "email"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {

...

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 * @Assert\Length(max="255")
 */
private $email;

...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Wefra\ADHSWebinarBundle\Entity\Webinar", inversedBy="registeredUsers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="webinar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $webinar;

...

}
```

What is happening is that, even though the two columns match the validation throws no error.

E.g. user1 hast the email `example@example.com` and webinar_id `6` and user2 tries to register with the same data without the validation generating an error.

I'm using Symfony2.5

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, i found the problem. The webinar was not set when validating the model. I had to set the webinar_id before validating the Model.